# how can i implement pedalboard effects to my music player in python

Tags: python, audio-player

as you can see i've attempted to add reverb but i dont really have any idea what im doing with this. im not sure what way is the most efficient way of going about this, perhaps to make a new playlist in the fxwindow where the effected audio would be placed? i assume its not possible to add effects real time whilst the audio is playing..? i struggle to follow the example given of pedalboard being used because they implement effects on a particular audio file already provided and named, whereas this uses filedialog. any working way of implementing the audio effects will help!

```
from pedalboard import Pedalboard, Chorus, Reverb, Compressor, Delay, Distortion, Gain, PitchShift
from tkinter import filedialog
from turtle import bgcolor
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import *
import os

def playsong():
    currentsong=playlist.get(ACTIVE)
    print(currentsong)
    mixer.music.load(currentsong)
    
    mixer.music.play()
def pausesong():
    
    mixer.music.pause()
def stopsong():
    
    mixer.music.stop()
def resumesong():
    
    mixer.music.unpause()   
def browse_file():
    global filename_path
    filename_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    add_to_playlist(filename_path)
    mixer.music.queue(filename_path)
def add_to_playlist(filename):
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    index = 0
    playlist.insert(index, filename_path)
    index += 1

def fx():

    fxwindow=Tk()
    fxwindow.title('audio effects')
    fxwindow.geometry("720x480+50+20")
    fxwindow.configure(bg='LightBlue')

    frame = Frame(fxwindow)
    frame.pack()





    
    board = Pedalboard([Chorus(), Reverb(room_size=0.5)])
    
    with songs as f:
        mixer = f.read(f.frames)
        samplerate = f.samplerate
    
    effected = board(songs)

    with songs('processed-output.wav', samplerate, effected.shape[0]) as f:
        f.write(effected)


    
   


    


root=Tk()
root.title('vokal')
mixer.init()


#playlist
playlist=Listbox(root,selectmode=SINGLE,bg="LightBlue",fg="white",font=('arial',15),width=50)
playlist.grid(columnspan=5)

#list for storing play
songs = []

for s in songs: #buttons
    playlist.insert(END,s)
playbtn=Button(root,text="play",command=playsong)
playbtn.config(font=('arial',20),bg="LightBlue",fg="white",padx=7,pady=7)
playbtn.grid(row=1,column=0)
pausebtn=Button(root,text="pause",command=pausesong)
pausebtn.config(font=('arial',20),bg="LightBlue",fg="white",padx=7,pady=7)
pausebtn.grid(row=1,column=1)
stopbtn=Button(root,text="stop",command=stopsong)
stopbtn.config(font=('arial',20),bg="LightBlue",fg="white",padx=7,pady=7)
stopbtn.grid(row=1,column=2)
Resumebtn=Button(root,text="resume",command=resumesong)
Resumebtn.config(font=('arial',20),bg="LightBlue",fg="white",padx=7,pady=7)
Resumebtn.grid(row=1,column=3)
addBtn=Button(root, text="import mp3 or wav file",command=browse_file)
addBtn.config(font=('arial',20),bg="LightBlue",fg="white",padx=7,pady=7)
addBtn.grid(row=1,column=4)
fxBtn=Button(root, text="audio effects",command=fx)
fxBtn.config(font=('arial',20),bg="LightBlue",fg="white",padx=7,pady=7)
fxBtn.grid(row=1,column=5)


mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't get any answers yet probably because you are asking a lot of questions about a niche library. I suggest you take another look at the given examples, try to understand how the library works and then try to add in what you want to do with it. Then, if you're stuck again, ask a very focused question with information on what you want to achieve, what you expect to happen and what actually happens instead.

Comment: A potential answer to your question about adding effects in real time can be found [on the Pedalboard Github page](https://github.com/spotify/pedalboard/issues/37).